# Multiple versions of eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Can I download the classic eclipse version and add packages that will get me any of the others that are offered for download?

I want the java development AND the C/C++ development versions but would like them in one eclipse installation. Is this possible or do I have to download two eclipses and keep two installations and run two versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the one eclipse install. All packages can be installed via the Install Software menu options. The only difference between the Java and C/C++ versions is the packages that have been preinstalled thus saving time in the beginning setup.